# Is it necessary to disconnect the battery when installing new RAM in the early 2011 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, repair

I want to install additional RAM to my early 2011 MacBook Pro.

I originally was only looking at the [official Apple guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270#link1), but then while searching for a better screwdriver I found the [iFixit guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-RAM/5117/1), which tells you to disconnect the battery.

Is this necessary? Apple's guide doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it without disconnecting the battery and it works fine, so disconnecting the battery is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In case your computer is really shut down it's not necessary since memory is not powered.

I believe ifixit instruction tend to be on safe side: for example this one is just to be sure that memory is really not powered and computer not just in sleep mode accidentally.